# How to have Vim launched and opening a specific folder at startup on MacOS?

Tags: mac, vim

Switching from TextMate to Vim, I'd like to have Vim launched and opening a specific folder at startup on MacOS?

Manually I can start Vim from the shell with `mvim someFolder`. I use MacOS 10.6 and NERDTree.

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

Reading and trying to apply the proposed answers (thanks by the way) I realize I was probably not clear enough in my question:

I want MacVim automatically launched at startup, and with opening a specific folder of mine. Later on during my MacOS session, if for any reason I open anew MacVim, I don't want it to open this specific folder, I want the MacVim default behavior.

I could do that with TextMate by going to MacOS System Preference, Accounts, Login Items and adding here my TextMate project file. As this project file was associated with TextMate, it was enough to have TextMate automatically launched at startup and displaying this project files list.

Is there a way to achieve this with Vim?

Comment: did you read my [last comment](http://superuser.com/questions/264208/how-to-have-vim-launched-and-opening-a-specific-folder-at-startup-on-macos/264347#264347)? I think it's the simplest way to achieve your goal. Try with this in your shell script : `cd /path/to/folder/ && mvim +NERDTree .` It does exactly what you want. You may combine it with @Jack M's [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/264208/how-to-have-vim-launched-and-opening-a-specific-folder-at-startup-on-macos/264515#264515) for a more customized workspace.

Comment: @romainl Sorry, I had missed your comment. I've just commented to your questions, indeed your solution is the easiest, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want MacVim to open the folder every time you might as well add an alias to your `.profile` or `.bashrc` like this:

```
alias vimm='mvim /path/to/some/folder'
```

This way, you can still launch MacVim for some task unrelated to the content of your folder (like editing your `.profile` or some config file) with the regular `mvim` command.

Comment: thanks, that sounds fine for me, but how then can I have this `vimm` be executed at MacOs startup?

Comment: @Florent2 You can create a shell script with the regular shebang plus this line: `mvim /path/to/some/folder` or simply `vimm` if you have created the alias, make it executable and add it to the list of startup items under the "Account" pane of System Preferences. Or use `launchd` or any of the probable dozen of solutions available.

Comment: thanks! I got your solution working, was the easiest for me (just had to change the extension of the shell script from .sh to .command, else the shell script would be opened in my default editor instead of being run during the MacOS startup)

Answer (score 1):

To open NERDTree to the specific directory you can add the following line to your `~/.gvimrc` (or `~/.vimrc` if you want it to work in console as well):

```
au VimEnter * NERDTreeToggle /path/to/your/folder/
```

Comment: thanks but when I add `NERDTreeToggle /path/to/my/folder/` to ~/.vimrc and then run `mvim` I get the error `Not an editor command: NERDTreeToggle /path/to/my/folder`. I'm new to vim, so I probably missed something obvious?

Comment: The vimrc is sourced before any plugins, so that command is not available. I have edited the answer to use an autocmd that will run when Vim has finished starting.

Comment: @ElIsra thanks it works but I want this behavior only at the MacOs startup. I've edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an applescript to run a shell command and add it to your startup items

```
-- Open MacVim
do shell script "/path/to/mvim /path/to/folder"
```

or

```
    -- Open Vim on the terminal
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "/path/to/vim /path/to/folder"
    end tell
```

using the AppleScript Editor.

Comment: thanks, finally I used the Romainl's solution, was the easiest for me. I tried yours, but the applescript would not be ran at startup, only be opened in the applescript editor. I suppose there was a some additional thing to setup (for instance for the shell script I had to change the extension from .sh to .command).

Comment: You can find some choices in the "Save as..." dialog.

Answer (score 1):

To make this launch at startup, you'll have to jump through some hoops.

#### Create a session file using `.vims` as the extension:

Open MacVim and open any/all of the files/tabs/NERDTrees you would like to have open.  Save this to a session with the `.vims` extension:

```
mksession! ~/Desktop/project.vims
```

This can go in any directory you'd like, I'm just using the Desktop for ease of use.

#### Create an Automator Application:

Open Automator and create a new Custom application.  Add a "Run Shell Script" action to your workflow.  Change the Shell to `/usr/bin/ruby`, and change the "Pass input" to "as arguments", then paste this code into the body of the action:

```
file_name = ARGV[0].split(' ').join('\ ')
command = %Q!/usr/local/bin/mvim -S "#{file_name}"!
system(command)
```

Check the location of `mvim` with `which`, and update as necessary.  Save the workflow (I put it in `~/Desktop/SU`) and change the "File Format" to "Application".

#### Associate your Automator Application with `.vims` files.

Right click on `~/Desktop/project.vims` and select "Get Info".  Under "Open with:", select your Automator Application, and tell it to "Change All...".

#### Drop into your Login Items.

Open System Preferences, Accounts, Your User, and select the "Login Items" tab.  Drag your `~/Desktop/project.vims` file into the list.

#### Done!

Log out and back in and MacVim should open automagically.

#### Limitations.

For some reason Automator keeps running while this session if VIM is active.  If anyone knows how to fix this, please let me know.

Comment: thank for your detailled answer! Finally I use Romainl's solution, was the easiest for me.

Answer (score 0):

What I find most useful is to open the project files in tabs using NERDTree and then make a session file:

```
mksession! project.vim
```

The exclamation mark is to overwrite the previous project.vim should you add a new file to the project. Then, anytime I want to fire up vim, I just have to call:

```
vim -S project.vim
```

I guess you could source the project.vim directly in the vimrc for a more automated approach.

Comment: thanks I could create the project.vim file but when I run `mvim -S project.vim` the NERDTree panel is empty.

Comment: @Florent2. I would add: set autochdir to the end of the generated vim file or to the vimrc. This way, when you source the file it will go straight to the directory of the buffer you are editing, thus filling the nerdtree.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately could not make it work with adding `set autochdir` in my vimrc file, and adding it to the generated vim file is not possible as I would to think to redo it each time I overwrite it.

Comment: @Florent2 You are right, I was not aware that the autochdir messed up with sessions. SO maybe you could just map some keystrokes to change into the current buffer's directory like this (proposed in http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip64): map ,cd :cd %:p:h<CR>:pwd<CR>